# Limit table cell to only one line of text? 'overflow' and 'white-space' not working

Tags: html, css, css-tables

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMhmS/152/)

I have a table w/ multiple columns and rows, and I'm trying to limit each cell to only one line of text. Second lines and beyond I want hidden because multiple lines disrupt the height of each table row.

First off, some sells contain `<p>` tags, and the following code is not fixing this issue:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 50px;
}
```

How can I effectively limit each cell to only one line of text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nowrap` works well in table cells, but you are using `<br>` forcing line to break. Simply enter some long text with spaces and you will see that it works fine:

```
<td><p>3 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5</p></td>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNk64/

If you will put `text-overflow:ellipsis;` and strip `<p>` tags, you can make it end with `...`:

http://jsfiddle.net/UNk64/2/

If You really wish to ignore `<br>` in td, you could use this css walkaround:

```
td br{
    line-height: 0px;
    display:none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UNk64/5/

Comment: And I take it that nowrap doesn't ignore <br> tags?

Comment: There is no `CSS` rule that can ignore `<br>` tags.

Comment: But there is walkaround for it... in post above.

Comment: Interessant 2nd link... `white-space: nowrap; + overflow: hidden; + text-overflow: ellipsis;` is perfect... thanks a lot!